# How to change the mirror of setuptools?

Tags: installation, package-management, python, mirrors

I changed the `~/.pip/pip.conf` file to a customized mirror, and `pip install` do download the package from that mirror. But when installing(run the `setup.py`), I find setuptools still get packages from `http://pypi.python.org/simple/`.

So how to change the mirror setuptools using? The system is Ubuntu 12.10 and setuptools version 0.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that `setuptools` is using `easy_install`, so you need to change the config file `~/.pydistutils.cfg` as well. An example could be:

```
[easy_install]  
index-url=http://mirror.site.url/simple
```